# Json: how to properly strip the escape characters with json.net

Tags: c#, json, string, json.net

I have json response in the below format.

```
"[{\\\"JobID\\\":\\\"1\\\",\\\"BillGenerationDate\\\":\\\"4/29/2013 2:53:34 PM\\\",\\\"BillID\\\":\\\"115743\\\",\\\"BillNo\\\":\\\"115743\\\",\\\"CustomerID\\\":\\\"4041705\\\",\\\"PayStatus\\\":\\\"0\\\",\\\"PaymentRequiredStatus\\\":\\\"True\\\",\\\"ProductName\\\":\\\"Epic FBO test\\\",\\\"Description\\\":\\\"Epic Automation 2\\\\r\\\\n\\\",\\\"ProductType\\\":\\\"eBill \\\",\\\"DueType\\\":\\\"-1\\\",\\\"DueDate\\\":\\\"2013-03-15\\\",\\\"Amount\\\":\\\"63.70\\\",\\\"Cost\\\":\\\"\\\"},
{\\\"JobID\\\":\\\"9\\\",\\\"BillGenerationDate\\\":\\\"5/2/2013 10:21:39 AM\\\",\\\"BillID\\\":\\\"115743\\\",\\\"BillNo\\\":\\\"115743\\\",\\\"CustomerID\\\":\\\"4041705\\\",\\\"PayStatus\\\":\\\"0\\\",\\\"PaymentRequiredStatus\\\":\\\"True\\\",\\\"ProductName\\\":\\\"FBO Test Product\\\",\\\"Description\\\":\\\"FBO Product Test\\\",\\\"ProductType\\\":\\\"eBill \\\",\\\"DueType\\\":\\\"-1\\\",\\\"DueDate\\\":\\\"2013-05-01\\\",\\\"Amount\\\":\\\"150.70\\\",\\\"Cost\\\":\\\"\\\"}]
```

I believe json.net handles the escape characters and I used the below code to deserialize it to a dictionary collection.

```
var billList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(contentCorrected);
```

But this json parsing throws exception 
"Invalid property identifier character: . Path '[0]', line 1, position 2."
Could we solve this by manipulating the json response string?

Comment: Try Regex.Unescape().
Detailed solution can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40188910/593932

Comment: Json.Parse(string) may help. See my answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52207034/2822307)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `string contentCorrected = contentCorrected.Replace(@"\", "");`before deserialization process.

Comment: It should be like `contentCorrected = contentCorrected.Replace(@"\""", @"""")`

Comment: or 
`contentCorrected = contentCorrected.Replace(@"\", string.Empty)`

Comment: this can lead to invalid json

Comment: Nowadays, I find this answer a bit "quick'n'dirty". I'd go with @Johan Alzate answer if you're still using Newtonsoft for serializing

Answer (score 22):

**THE SHORT ANSWER:** first you need to deserialize the escaped string, but not to the target CLR type, but deserialize to another string (repeat if necessary); then, it is deserialized to the target type:

```
// Initial example json string:  "\"{\\\"Property1\\\":1988,\\\"Property2\\\":\\\"Some data :D\\\"}\""


// First, deserialize to another string (unescaped string).
string unescapedJsonString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(escapedJsonString);
Debug.WriteLine(unescapedJsonString);
// Prints:
// "{\"Property1\":1988,\"Property2\":\"Some data :D\"}"


// Second, deserialize to another string, again (in this case is necessary)
var finalUnescapedJsonString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(unescapedJsonString);
Debug.WriteLine(finalUnescapedJsonString);
// This time prints a final, unescaped, json string:
// {"Property1":1988,"Property2":"Some data :D"}


// Finally, perform final deserialization to the target type, using the last unescaped string.
MyClass targetObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(finalUnescapedJsonString);
```

**LONG ANSWER (but interesting)**
Using `string.Replace(...` could generate an invalid string, because it could damage certain special characters that needed the backslash to be deserialized correctly .

This type of **escaped strings** are usually generated when a string that was already a json string, its serialized again (or even more times). This causes something like "various levels of serialization" (it really is a serialization of a string with reserved characters), and the result is backshash characters (or groups of one, two or more backslash followed: \, \, \\\) scattered all over the string.
So, to remove them correctly is not enough to replace them by empty.

**THE RIGHT WAY:** A better way to get a **unescaped string** would be to do a first deserialization to string type (Repeat this several times if necessary), And then do a final deserialization to target CLR type:

```
// -- SERIALIZATION --

// Initial object
MyClass originObj = new MyClass { Property1 = 1988, Property2 = "Some data :D" };

// "First level" Of serialization.
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(originObj);
Debug.WriteLine(jsonString);
// Prints: 
// {"Property1":1988,"Property2":"Some data :D"}


// "Second level" of serialization.
string escapedJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonString);
Debug.WriteLine(escapedJsonString);            
// "{\"Property1\":1988,\"Property2\":\"Some data :D\"}"
// Note the initial and final " character and de backslash characters

// ...
// at this point you could do more serializations ("More levels"), Obtaining as a result more and more backslash followed,
// something like this:
// "\"{\\\"Property1\\\":1988,\\\"Property2\\\":\\\"Some data :D\\\"}\""
// Note that is... very very crazy :D
// ...

// -- DESERIALIZATION --

// First deserialize to another string (unescaped string).
string unescapedJsonString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(escapedJsonString);
Debug.WriteLine(unescapedJsonString);
// Prints:
// {"Property1":1988,"Property2":"Some data :D"}

// ...
// at this point you could repeat more deserializations to string, if necessary. For example if you have many backslash \\\
// ...

// Finally, perform final deserialization to the target type, using the last unescaped string.
MyClass targetObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(unescapedJsonString);
```

Comment: been stuck on something for days, thank you! you're absolutely right!!

Comment: This seems to be the safest way.

Answer (score 1):

1.Remove all the `\` character before you deserialize it. Use replace function.

```
yourJsonString.Replace("\\\\\\\\\", "");
```

2.Your Json string is incomplete or does not seem to be of type `List<Dictionary<string, string>>"`. Correct the type you want the JSON to be converted.
I modified your JSON a little as follows and it worked.

```
newJson = "{\"array\":" + yourJsonString + "}"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs when valid double quotes are used within the answer. Removing and/or Replacing won't solved this in all cases.
It frustrated me too until I found a simple solution:

```
var billList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(@contentCorrected);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the code below works

```
string contentCorrected = contentCorrected.Replace(@"\""", "");
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile?