# Replacing escape characters from JSON

Tags: c#, json, string, replace

I want to replace the "\" character from a JSON string by a empty space.
How can I do that?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/q/16331770/72324

Comment: Similar post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253367/how-to-escape-a-json-string-containing-newline-characters-using-javascript. Check it out.

Comment: Just a guess but, I don't think you need to replace any chars. Probably you check the json string using your debugger (hint: use the magnifier icon to see the original text).

Answer (score 47):

I have found that the easiest and best way to remove all escape characters from your JSON string, is to pass the string into **Regex.Unescape()** method. 
This method returns a new string with no ecapes, even \n \t etc, are removed.

**See this MSDN article for more details**: 
[Regex.Unescape Method (String) (System.Text.RegularExpressions)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This is the only right answer. Blindly just replacing all \ characters with empty will not work when you have \ in the json content.

Comment: I know this question is a bit old, but is there a reason why no one has suggested just deserializing the JSON as a string? Like: `var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(escapedJson);` Surely JSON serializers are built for this?

Comment: I agree with @JamieTwells. First, deserialize to another string (unescaped string): `string unescapedJsonString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(escapedJsonString);` (you can repeat this many times), then, you can deserialize, again, as a target type: `MyClass targetObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(finalUnescapedJsonString);`

Comment: Doesn't work.

`str = Regex.Unescape("\r \n a"); >str "\r \n a"`

Comment: @WULF You're *using* escapes, but the resulting string does not *contain* escapes. Try `Regex.Unescape("\\r \\b a")`;

Answer (score 26):

If the json object is a string, in .Net the escape "\" characters are added, should you want to clean up the json string, JObject.Parse({string}) as demonstrated in the following code snippet cleans up nicely:

```
var myJsonAsString = "{\"Name\": \"John\", \"LastName\": \"Doe\", \"Age\": 199 }";

var myCleanJsonObject = JObject.Parse(myJsonAsString);
```

Should give us a clean Json object with the escape characters removed.

```
{
"Name": "John",
"LastName": "Doe",
"Age": 199
}
```

Comment: In my case, I have to do that after serialize the object. string dirty = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);
            return JObject.Parse(dirty).ToString();

Comment: Your original string from `var myJsonAsString` already has no `\​​` (backslashes) in it. To get a backslash in a string, use `"\\"`. Which will then throw, because `JObject.Parse` will consider backslashes, unless followed by a legal escape character, illegal JSON (and correctly so).

Answer (score 22):

This type of **escaped strings** are usually generated when you try to encode a string of JSON into JSON a second time.
This causes something like "various levels of serialization"

**Solution:**

- First, you need to deserialize the escaped string, but not to the target CLR type, but deserialize to another string
- Repeat deserialization to string type again, if necessary.
- Then perform final deserialization to the target type:

Code:

```
// Initial example json string:  "\"{\\\"Property1\\\":1988,\\\"Property2\\\":\\\"Some data :D\\\"}\""    

// First, deserialize to another string (unescaped string).
string unescapedJsonString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(escapedJsonString);
// Result: "{\"Property1\":1988,\"Property2\":\"Some data :D\"}"

// Second, deserialize to another string, again (in this case is necessary)
var finalUnescapedJsonString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(unescapedJsonString);
// {"Property1":1988,"Property2":"Some data :D"}   This time prints a final, unescaped, json string:

// Finally, perform final deserialization to the target type, using the last unescaped string.
MyClass targetObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(finalUnescapedJsonString);
```

Comment: it crashes for me with this approach

Comment: Best approach. (Y)

Comment: this does work! in my case I just needed one deserialization step, not both of them.

Comment: dude - thanks to you, I've found a real nasty bug in 3rd party API!

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>("{\"Property1\":1988,\"Property2\":\"Some data :D\"}")` gives me this error message in .NET 6: `Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: P. Path '', line 1, position 3.`

Answer (score 10):

`Regex.Unescape()` method will work just fine in most cases, but some particular cases require custom replacements. E.g. `Regex.Unescape()` will generate actual line breaks which are [not supported in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392766/multiline-strings-in-json).

**Unescaped JSON:**

```
{"comments_count":27,"comments":"<a name=\"comments\"><\/a>\n\n\t\n\t\n\t\t\n\t<div class=\"CommentsList\">\n\t\t<strong>COMENTARII<\/strong>\n\t\t"}
```

**Regex.Unescape**

```
{"comments_count":27,"comments":"<a name="comments"></a>

Replacements
    <div class="CommentsList">
        <strong>Comments</strong>
"}
```

**Custom replacements**

```
private string SanitizeReceivedJson(string uglyJson)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(uglyJson);
    sb.Replace("\\\t", "\t");
    sb.Replace("\\\n", "\n");
    sb.Replace("\\\r", "\r");
    return sb.ToString();
}

{"comments_count":27,"comments":"<a name=\"comments\"><\/a>\n\n\t\n\t\n\t\t\n\t<div class=\"CommentsList\">\n\t\t<strong>COMENTARII<\/strong>"}
```

Comment: Doesn't work.

`str = Regex.Unescape("\r \n a"); >str "\r \n a"`

Comment: @WULF looks like you added that comment to every answer that mentioned Regex.Unescape, whereas this answer explicitly calls out `\r` `\n` and `\t` as characters that it doesn't process.

Answer (score 0):

C# string assignment does that for you, although if name or value contains \ it will be double escaped.
The proper way is to use variable.Replace("\\\\","\\"); or variable.Replace(@"\\",@"\");
This will remove double escaped \ character, Leaving REQUIRED \ in value. for example if JSON contains "Domain\Username" this will be returned as \"Domain\\\\Username\" assigning that to string will result you will have Domain\\Username

Answer (score 0):

deserialize to another string then to your class

```
string resultString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(content);
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(resultString);
```

This worked for me.

Comment: How is this different from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54430289/70345) posted in 2019?

Answer (score -1):

In c# you have only one way to create standard JSON result:

You must be add one class with your custom property name and then return Json(myClassForJsonResult) as bottom code:

```
public ActionResult testJsonData()
{
    var myClassForJsonResult=new YourClassOfYourCustomProperties();
    myClassForJsonResult.FirstPropertyStringType="first";
    myClassForJsonResult.SecondPropertyIntType=2;

    return Json(myClassForJsonResult);
}
```

class Defination:

```
    public class YourClassOfYourCustomProperties
    {
        public string FirstPropertyStringType{ get; set; }
        public int SecondPropertyIntType{ get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Regex.Unescape(yourEscapedString);

Comment: Doesn't work.

`str = Regex.Unescape("\r \n a"); >str "\r \n a"`

Answer (score -1):

var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement> (escapedJson)