# C# parse array in json

Tags: c#, json

I have following `json` structure:

```
{
    [{
        "name": "2542",
        "type": "FOLDER",
        "size": 0,
        "time": 0,
        "items": [{
            "name": "10-1432927746000.ksf",
            "type": "FILE",
            "size": 225,
            "time": 1433019520,
            "items": null,
            "info": {
                "seller": 10,
                "count": 2
            }
        }],
        "info": null
    }]
}
```

how can I parse it with C#? I have try `var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json)` but the result is an error:

> Invalid property identifier character: [. Path '', line 1, position 1.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16333468/4810628

Comment: I'm not so sure this is valid JSON to being with; the outermost array should start with an identifier e.g { "things":[....]}

Comment: This is invalid `JSON`. Check http://jsonlint.com/. You start with an object and right inside put an array without property name.

Comment: It's an array or a single object? Try without the first braces!

Comment: you can use below answer or you can remove outer curly braces { }.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complementing the @Stephen awswer, you can yet use only the inner array, like in [this sample](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm#ID2RBToggle).

```
[{
        "name": "2542",
        "type": "FOLDER",
        "size": 0,
        "time": 0,
        "items": [{
            "name": "10-1432927746000.ksf",
            "type": "FILE",
            "size": 225,
            "time": 1433019520,
            "items": null,
            "info": {
                "seller": 10,
                "count": 2
            }
        }],
        "info": null
    }]
```

Anyway, the issue seems to be your original json realy. =)

Answer (score 3):

The JSON posted doesn't [lint](http://jsonlint.com/) so I suspect this is the root of your problem.

However this does:

```
{
    "things":[{
        "name": "2542",
        "type": "FOLDER",
        "size": 0,
        "time": 0,
        "items": [{
            "name": "10-1432927746000.ksf",
            "type": "FILE",
            "size": 225,
            "time": 1433019520,
            "items": null,
            "info": {
                "seller": 10,
                "count": 2
            }
        }],
        "info": null
    }]
}
```

Note how the outermost array has now has an identifier [which is required](http://json.org/); that is to say your parsed object will have a `things` property which is an array of that inner structure.